# Wagtail 2.11.2 internationalisation, translated pages not created automatically nor accesible

Tags: internationalization, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I'm testing Wagtail 2.11.2 new Content Internationalization approach:

1. I've setup two models HomePage and GenericPage.
2. I've setup Locales in settings.py and in Admin

```
USE_I18N = True
WAGTAIL_I18N_ENABLED = True
USE_L10N = True

LANGUAGE_CODE='en'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', "English"),
    ('es', "Spanish"),
    ('de', "German"),
]

WAGTAIL_CONTENT_LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', "English"),
    ('es', "Spanish"),
]
```

3. I'm able to create pages in the admin and I'm asked the language for that particular page, I choose a language.
4. After I press Publish I only see the page I've just created. I don't see the translated version neither a link to create the translated version of that page.

Are page translations version created automatically or is there something I'm missing? I've checked the documentation and is not quite clear about this behavior.

What should I expect to see for managing translations?

Thanks in advance,

Marcos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wagtail itself only provides the basic infrastructure for serving pages in multiple languages, not the UI for translating between them. [As per the docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/i18n.html#overview):

> Wagtail provides the infrastructure for creating and serving content in multiple languages, but does not itself provide an admin interface for managing translations of the same content across different languages. For this, the [wagtail-localize](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-localize) app must be installed separately.